# Magento: Are there stats on install base (by version) for module developers?

Tags: magento, module, version

As the question states, I am preparing to deploy my first couple modules on the Magento Connect store and want to make sure I am targeting the best versions. Testing on 1.3 is proving to be a bit of a pain, and if only a few people use that version I would rather spend the time making the modules better!

Google hasn't helped as yet, though I think the keywords I use are getting picked up as other more specific technical questions (Google Base, for example).

Does this information exist? What about your personal experience? For me, I have only encountered installations below 1.5 Community (1.10 Enterprise) for upgrade projects. I haven't personally encountered a client that is on 1.4 and plans to stay on 1.4.

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a signification amount of people who have older versions and wont upgrade because of the complexity and the amount of modification they have done to their stores.
Most people right now who are on community version seem to be on 1.5 or 1.6, but if you want to test older versions just download from the archive install locally and see if it works for the older versions.
Here is a link to the downloadable versions of magento, in case you decide to test on those older versions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download - click released archived tab at the top

Comment: Thanks. I have a test bed VM setup for testing 1.3-1.6 and 1.9-1.11. I did manage to resolve my issues in 1.3, so I think I will release for that version.